# gradient's norm is greater than epsilon, implies the function unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, gradient-descent, mean-value-theorem

I am trying to prove a step from a larger problem, and I think that it's correct because the geometry intuition that the function is decreasing on the direction that is opposite to the gradient and doesn't have minimum point. But I can't figure out how to show it, I have tried to use a methos that is similar to the gradient method combining the mean value theorem but it didn't work out.

the question is:
$for f : R^n \to R, f \in C^1(R^n)$

fix $\epsilon > 0:$

$if\ ||\nabla f(x)|| > \epsilon\ \forall\ x \in R^n  $

does it imply that $f$ is unbounded from below?
i.e for every $M < 0 $ there exists $x_m \in R^n $ s.t $f(x_m) < M$?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You want to show the case $n=1$ first, which is a bit easier to imagine. Then realize that the general case reduces to the easy case.

Comment: For $n=1$ show that the derivative has a sign and then it becomes an application of the mean value theorem.

Comment: To show that $n=1$ implies the general result, just examine the behavior of $f$ along some line. To show the case for $n=1$, what can you say about $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,dx$ when $g > \epsilon > 0$ everywhere, or when $g < -\epsilon$ everywhere?